# Como ler uma variável do tipo unsigned char pela função fscanf?

Tags: c, arquivo, matriz, conversão-de-tipo

Estou lendo uma matriz de um arquivo onde cada elemento dessa matriz varia de 0 a 255. Por esse motivo armazenei os valores dentro de uma matriz do tipo unsigned char, mas estou encontrando alguns problemas no que diz respeito a qual especificador usar. Quando uso o especificador %i e armazeno ele em uma variável unsigned char aparecem warnings na hora da compilação, indicando conflito de tipos das variáveis. Existe algum especificador para o unsigned char, ou alguma forma de fazer um typecast dentro da própria função fcanf, sem que dê nenhum warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o seu compilador está funcionando em modo C99, o [especificador que você quer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) é `"%hhu"`:

```
if (fscanf(entrada, "%hhu ", &elemento) < 1) {
    /* tratar erro de leitura, o arquivo provavelmente está corrompido */
}
```

Os formatos de `printf()` e `scanf()` para valores numéricos são o seguinte:

```
tipo        signed   unsigned
char        %hhd     %hhu
short int   %hd      %hu
int         %d       %u
long        %ld      %lu
long long   %lld     %llu
intmax_t    %jd      %ju
size_t      %zd      %zu
ptrdiff_t   %td      %tu
```

Alternativamente, para auxiliar (?) a portabilidade, você pode usar os macros definidos em `<inttypes.h>`. Estes macros expandem para literais de *string* que devem ser concatenados com o resto da sua string de formato, se houver necessidade. Há macros separados para `printf()` e `scanf()`; os tipos para o `scanf()` são conforme a tabela abaixo:

```
tipo        signed   unsigned
 8 bits     SCNd8    SCNu8
16 bits     SCNd16   SCNu16
32 bits     SCNd32   SCNu32
64 bits     SCNd64   SCNu64
intmax_t    SCNdMAX  SCNuMAX
intptr_t    SCNdPTR  SCNuPTR
```

Usa-se como:

```
if (fscanf(entrada, SCNd8, &elemento) < 1) {
    /* tratar erro de leitura, o arquivo provavelmente está corrompido */
}
```

A referência acima, que se refere ao padrão ISO da linguagem C, lembra que o especificador `"%i"`é perigoso, já que ele tenta adivinhar via prefixo a base do número que está lendo (além de ter naturalmente sinal). Assim, se no seu arquivo houver um número escrito como `011`, ele vai ler 9 em vez de 11.